# openstack cinder : volume:create: No valid host was found. No weighed hosts available

Tags: ubuntu, openstack, cinder, openstack-cinder

I am trying to get a working openstack liberty in one of our dev servers that has minimal configuration and has ubuntu 14:04.

All the components looks good and I was able to create instance and view the dashboard too.

Now, I am trying to create a volume and this is where I am facing an issue.

We have a node that has a disk 'sda' with 8GB and we followed the steps listed here to prepare the disk.
https://eatpeppershothot.blogspot.sg/2016/04/use-real-block-storage-backend-for.html

**​output of lsblk​**

NAME                             FSTYPE      LABEL MOUNTPOINT

sda                              xfs

└─sda1                           LVM2_member

​

Then we followed the standard documentation 
http://docs.openstack.org/liberty/install-guide-ubuntu/cinder-storage-install.html

**On Controller node**

```
**root@dev-controller:~/scripts# cinder service-list**
+------------------+----------------+----------+---------+-------+----------------------------+-----------------+
|      Binary      |      Host      |   Zone   |  Status | State |         Updated_at         | Disabled Reason |
+------------------+----------------+----------+---------+-------+----------------------------+-----------------+
| cinder-scheduler | dev-controller |   nova   | enabled |   up  | 2016-08-04T12:03:55.000000 |        -        |
|  cinder-volume   |  dev-osd1@lvm  |   osd1   | enabled |   up  | 2016-08-04T12:03:51.000000 |        -        |
|  cinder-volume   |  dev-osd2@lvm  | dev-osd2 | enabled |   up  | 2016-08-04T12:03:54.000000 |        -        |
|  cinder-volume   |  dev-osd3@lvm  |   nova   | enabled |   up  | 2016-08-04T12:03:55.000000 |        -        |
+------------------+----------------+----------+---------+-------+----------------------------+-----------------+
```

​By default all the volumes were listed under "nova" zone but we changed it to different node while trying things out.

Command to create volume
cinder create --volume_type lvm --display_name testvol 1 --availability-zone dev-osd2
cinder create --volume_type lvm --display_name testb 1

The 'cinder create' command works but 'cinder list' command shows that the volume is in error state.
Both of these commands end up in error state.

**cinder-scheduler.log**

```
2016-08-04 20:11:46.466 3461 INFO cinder.openstack.common.scheduler.base_filter [req-d1e3c63e-0d15-42cc-af3f-7867689cf4fe db30662c15f44a5e9b4cdd3fb5125762 0d1a9f632e4c4dd3a090c7c377fbcc77 - - -] Filter AvailabilityZoneFilter returned 0 host(s)
2016-08-04 20:11:46.469 3461 ERROR cinder.scheduler.flows.create_volume [req-d1e3c63e-0d15-42cc-af3f-7867689cf4fe db30662c15f44a5e9b4cdd3fb5125762 0d1a9f632e4c4dd3a090c7c377fbcc77 - - -] Failed to run task cinder.scheduler.flows.create_volume.ScheduleCreateVolumeTask;volume:create: No valid host was found. No weighed hosts available
2016-08-04 20:11:46.471 3461 DEBUG cinder.volume.flows.common [req-d1e3c63e-0d15-42cc-af3f-7867689cf4fe db30662c15f44a5e9b4cdd3fb5125762 0d1a9f632e4c4dd3a090c7c377fbcc77 - - -] Updating volume: 89a42d39-f7a9-41ce-84b7-76160d444597 with {'status': 'error'} due to: No valid host was found. No weighed hosts available _update_object /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/volume/flows/common.py:87
```

I have checked and made sure that all the database connect string are correct and that the host are able to connect to the controller. RabbitMQ is fine too.

**OUTPUT from pvdisplay**

```
root@dev-osd2:~# pvdisplay
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/vda5
  VG Name               dev-mon01-vg
  PV Size               15.57 GiB / not usable 2.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              3986
  Free PE               6
  Allocated PE          3980
  PV UUID               gux2KI-5hbS-VSOf-RLaQ-dCk8-ZXCX-oBOocf

  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda1
  VG Name               cinder-volumes
  PV Size               8.00 GiB / not usable 2.98 MiB
  Allocatable           yes
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              2047
  Free PE               2047
  Allocated PE          0
  PV UUID               AfjDlL-vSjm-stE4-4jPJ-ze7G-dH1f-GmWLSv
```

**OUTPUT from vgdisplay**

```
 --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               cinder-volumes
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  1
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                0
  Open LV               0
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               8.00 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              2047
  Alloc PE / Size       0 / 0
  Free  PE / Size       2047 / 8.00 GiB
  VG UUID               P6t7E7-TQqq-zhEW-HAX8-CFl6-kkH3-q3Aova
```

Please help me figure this out :)

Regards

Comment: Can you please post the log of pvdisplay and vgdisplay

Comment: Would you please edit your post to use highlighting/formating when appropriate. Did it ever work before you "changed [things] to different node while trying thigs out". What does/do the log files of your `cinder-volume` service/-s say when starting and when/if receiving a request?

Comment: Hello I have the same problem @Sbal Did you solve?

Answer (score 0):

We had integrated cinder with ceph , we had to add the ceph secret key to all our compute nodes which we did not do before. Once we did that, it worked fine